# movie ID : about a group of teenagers being killed on a floating wood deck

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification

I've had this movie on my mind for a long time now.

It is about a group of teenagers going to a lake for a day off. They embark on a floating wood deck and they let themselves float free over the lake.

Suddenly they start to see a sort of "mud puddle". This thing is getting closer to them and suddenly tries to reach for them through the crack on the wood deck, it even manages to make some of the teenagers to fall and the "mud puddle" kinda swallows them.

It ends with one of the teenagers finally capable of reaching the shore, but she or he crawls too slow and the "mud puddle" manages to get its last victim. and then the movie or episode comes to a silent end with the sound of the flapping water.

If anyone could help me here I've seen this on TV in the mid 90s.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: That's one of the segments from Creepshow 2.

Comment: @Richard - move it to movies SE? Do we have the power?

Comment: @Omegacron - Nah. It's fantasy which means it's ours. It is a dupe though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Stephen King's "The Raft" as seen in Creepshow 2](http://stephenking.wikia.com/wiki/The_Raft)

One of three segments in the film, "The Raft" has a group of teenagers swimming out to an old wooden raft in the middle of a lake, only to find themselves the unwitting prey of a creature that resembles an oil slick or puddle of black goo. As the creature devours them one by one, the teenagers desperately try to find a way of getting back to shore.

In print form, "The Raft" was most famously included in the 1985 book [Skeleton Crew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_Crew).

Comment: Link answers are discouraged. This is probably the right answer, but you should expand on it by explaining the plot or why you think it's the answer. We want an answer that will still work five years from now.

Comment: I agree with this statement... however, that completely solve my headache lol short and sweet but with some simple word that comes from you woulda been nice :)

Comment: I concur, @Omegacron; I can only plead that I couldn't think of anything more intelligent to say about it :), and thank Richard for adding some value to the post.

Comment: @gowenfawr - in addition to Richard's video, I added a brief summary of what the segment is about. Feel free to edit as needed.