# Story Identification: movie with an algae like creature in a pond

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie a long time ago and I remember only bits of it. There is this pond where few friends go swimming and there will an algae like creature. It is like a blanket spread on water. Two people a boy and a girl get stuck in the middle of the pond on a log-boat and this creature consumes the girl from underneath the boat and meanwhile the guy escapes and reaches the bank. He then standing at the end of the bank makes this victory signs and expressions. The creature then jumps out of the pond and drags him in as well. The camera then moves away from the pond and it shows a sign "NO SWIMMING" covered in bushes and at this point the frame goes comic-book style. Drawings, black and white and all. I vaguely remember this as one of the three stories in the movie but am not sure of this last statement.

Comment: Sounds like ["The Raft"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creepshow_2), which was also the subject of [this old question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/movie-id-about-a-group-of-teenagers-being-killed-on-a-floating-wood-deck) and [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32281/can-you-identifiy-this-short-about-teenagers-on-a-raft-getting-swallowed-up-by-a/32283#32283).

Comment: @user14111 "The Raft" it is. Thanks a ton. Looks like I do not have enough reputation to upvote your comment but I really wish I could.

Comment: @Gautham: S'alright. Upvoting comments doesn't do much other than possibly working toward a badge. Incidentally, your question was marked as a duplicate because it's been answered before. This is not a criticism of your question, merely a way in which we try to avoid reduplication of effort by raising up the best question with the best answer. Cheers.

Comment: Good ol' Raft - this question gets asked a lot.